# VM/LXC asks AAAA record in a IPV6 disabled proxmox cluster

Tags: dns, ipv6, proxmox

I have a Proxmox cluster with IPv6 disabled. Following setting made on `/etc/sysctl.conf`:

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1
```

When I do DNS lookup, system asks for `AAAA` record instead of `A` record.
How is this possible?

Whether any Linux based VM/LXC with IPv6 will work on that cluster?

The IPv6 IP of vm/lxc will active even though cluster IPv6 property has disabled already?